# Integer solutions for eighth power Diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation $x^8+y^8=n$ for integers $x$ and $y$ and a given $n$ which is quite large (about 160 decimal digits). There's a hint that $x$ and $y$ may be not too different.

I tried $x=int(\sqrt[8]{\frac{n}{2}})$ and then increasing $x$ by one in each step, checking whether $n-x^8$ is itself an eighth power. Did that in Python, had no luck after letting the program run for some time.

Any ideas how to speed up the search?

Comment: You can use results on representations of integers by $x^2+y^2$. Look at [Binary quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form).

Comment: Maybe you can do modulo considerations that would constrain the form of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try to follow up on them toward a solution.

Comment: If you publish your $n$ maybe we can try too.

Comment: My $n$ is 17223507887602526420151651536619310810581211968884712600471622453277672311605232817186376770608196483963283605920702226380449555021499188148868557483176337161377.
It's from a challenge of the Mystery Twister website (https://www.mysterytwisterc3.org). Of course, if I'm not able to solve the equation myself I won't submit the solution there.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Somos you can try first Gaussian integer factorization.

There are various resources on the net, that can help you performing this task.
This URL for instance works with numbers as large as your $n$ : 
https://www.alpertron.com.ar/GAUSSIAN.HTM

It happens in this case that the returned numbers are perfect $4^{th}$ powers thus a solution is $$99778214590404624163^{\ 8}+96305429813873971636^{\ 8}$$

Answer (score 0):

Solving in **pari/gp**:

```
? n=17223507887602526420151651536619310810581211968884712600471622453277672311605232817186376770608196483963283605920702226380449555021499188148868557483176337161377;
?
? Q=bnfinit(x^8+1);
?
? N=bnfisnorm(Q, n)
%1 = [Mod(99778214590404624163*x^3 - 3472784776530652527*x^2 + 3472784776530652527*x + 96305429813873971636, x^8 + 1), 1]
?
? f=lift(N[1]);
?
? x=polcoeff(f, 0)
%2 = 96305429813873971636
?
? y=polcoeff(f, 3)
%3 = 99778214590404624163
?
? x^8+y^8==n
%4 = 1
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with pari/gp but after reading your post I installed it and copied your code into it's command line. It found the solution super-quickly. That's impressive!
Thanks a lot!